# how can $4x^2y^2=z^n$ where $x$,$y$ and $z$ are positive integers and $n$ is an odd integer?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

1. Am I right to think like as $4=2^2$, the prime factorization of $4x^2y^2$ consists of prime numbers on even powers only.
2. So the only way the statement for odd $n$ is true only if $z=p^{2k}$ because then at $z^n=(p^{2k})^n$ here n can be odd and this is the only way. Am I right?
3. If it is true then $4x^2y^2=p^{2kn}$, which means that $2xy=p^{kn}$, $xy=(p^{kn})/2$ and we have two ways: kn is even, or kn is odd. Am I right?

4/A. If $kn$ is even then if $p$ is odd, then there is no integer solution for $xy=(p^{kn})/2$. Am I right?

4/B. If $kn$ is even then if $p$ is even, then there an integer solution for $xy=(p^{kn})/2$ if $y=4x^2$, because then $y^2=16x^4,\ 4x^2y^2= 64x^6,$ but there are other solutions, too.

Can you help me how to continue?

Comment: 1. is true. 2. no it's wrong $z$ might be $p^{2k}q^{2m}$ for instance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: yes, z might be $p^(2k)q^(2m)$ sure, but for simplicity I used only one prime factor. The logic will be the same later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go this way.

If $n$ is odd $z=w^2$ and $w^n=2xy$

Deal with the factor $2$ first. If $2^r$ is either the least power of $2$ which divides $x$, or $r=n-1$ if the least power is $2^n$ or more, then with $x=2^rx_1, y=2^{n-r-1}y_1, w=2w_1$ we reduce to $x_1y_1=w_1^n$

You can take an arbitrary $n$ and an arbitrary $w_1$ and factorise $w_1^n$ how you like and then adjust for the residual power of $2$ by reworking the computation backwards.